# React: Patching package.json using patch-package

Tags: reactjs, npm, patch-package

I am using the `patch-package` to patch a package.json file of one of my dependencies. I modified the package.json and ran `npx patch-package [dependency_name]` but it not capturing the changes made to the package.json. However, changes made to other files like index.js are captured. How do I patch the package.json? I am trying to modify the module and jsnext:main attributes.

Comment: If i good understand the patch script is runing in 'postinstall' so changes made to package.json  will not apply to code because then you will have to run upgrade or install after modification again. (easy to go in loop).

Comment: You can write your own script witch will fire after installation. You will have to go to dir and run npm install package name@version

Answer (score 21):

```
npx patch-package some-package --exclude 'nothing'
```

https://github.com/ds300/patch-package/issues/49#issuecomment-646581987

Comment: I saw this, but it does not work.

Comment: @phatmann this did work in my case

Comment: I found I could apply the patch made this way via ```postinstall": "patch-package --exclude nothing",``` in my package.json

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to use this for the [same purpose](https://github.com/CareLuLu/react-native-web-ui-components/pull/490), alas the answer is *no* from what I can tell.

The patch process comes after `postinstall` which means that the `package.json` is already processed with the invalid dependencies.

Aside from just creating a PR, I revendored the library and made my modifications as I cannot wait for a merge.